# How can I use resource strings in object? - Android

Tags: android, string

I have a code in Android like this;

```
public static final String[] URLS = new String[]{"https://www.url1.com/","https://www.url2.com"};
```

I wanna make this code like this;

```
public static final String[] URLS = new String[]{"@strings/url_1","@strings/url_2"};
```

I tried too much code but it didn't work. What can I do about it?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Resources](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getString(int)) to get strings from android resources.Try below

`Resources res = context.getResources();
public static final String[] URLS = new String[]{res.getString(R.string.url_1), res.getString(R.string.url_2)};`

Answer (score 1):

@string resources are saved by there int references in R.java file. So, you can't use them directly. However, there is another way to do that.

You can use string-array in arrays.xml file. It would be like..

```
<string-array name="urls">
    <item>https://www.url1.com/</item>
    <item>https://www.url2.com/</item>
    <item>https://www.url3.com/</item>
</string-array>
```

In your Java Code, you can access it through following code.

```
public static final String[] URLS = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.urls);
```